# Delete documents using lucene 4 and retrieve all docIds of deleted docs

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene 4 to persist my data. The problem I'm facing right now is the following:

How to delete documents from the index and then retrieve the docIds of the deleted documents?

Here is the method I use to delete the documents:

```
Query query = new BooleanQuery();
...
indexWriter.deleteDocuments(query);
```

but once this method invoked, I haven't found a way (method or callback) to get deleted documents (and their fields).

Does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in one call.

As Lucene deletes don't happen immediately (extra `commit()` is required), returning deleted document ids would be a bit ambiguous. If you look inside delete method, it actually just adds jobs to one of the delete queues. That said, `commit()` doesn't return anything related to this either ;-(

Anyway, the only way I can think of is to run your `query`, gather documents/document IDs and run the `deleteDocuments(query)` afterwards. You might get some overlap (say if another thread would delete the same documents) but this is inevitable because of the `commit()` phase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It looks like querying is inevitable (too bad, I wanted to avoid it...).